# (Java) Get value of string loaded into dynamic-type object?

Tags: java, string

I'm very new to Java (~10 days), so my code is probably pretty bad, but here's what I've got:

```
ArgsDataHolder argsData = new ArgsDataHolder();  // a class that holds two
                                                 // ArrayList's where each element
                                                 // representing key/value args
Class thisArgClass;
String thisArgString;
Object thisArg;

for(int i=2; i< argsString.length; i++) {
    thisToken = argsString[i];
    thisArgClassString = getClassStringFromToken(thisToken).toLowerCase();
    System.out.println("thisArgClassString: " + thisArgClassString);
    thisArgClass = getClassFromClassString(thisArgClassString);

    // find closing tag; concatenate middle
    Integer j = new Integer(i+1);
    thisArgString = getArgValue(argsString, j, "</" + thisArgClassString + ">");

    thisArg = thisArgClass.newInstance();
    thisArg = thisArgClass.valueOf(thisArgString);
    argsData.append(thisArg, thisArgClass);
}
```

The user basically has to input a set of key/value arguments into the command prompt in this format: `<class>value</class>`, e.g. `<int>62</int>`.  Using this example, `thisArgClass` would be equal to `Integer.class`, `thisArgString` would be a string that read "62", and `thisArg` would be an instance of Integer that is equal to 62.

I tried `thisArg.valueOf(thisArgString)`, but I guess `valueOf(<String>)` is only a method of certain subclasses of Object.  For whatever reason, I can't seem to be able to cast thisArg to thisArgClass (like so: `thisArg = (thisArgClass)thisArgClass.newInstance();`, at which point `valueOf(<String>)` should become accessible.

There's got to be a nice, clean way of doing this, but it is beyond my abilities at this point.  How can I get the value of the string loaded into a dynamically-typed object (Integer, Long, Float, Double, String, Character, Boolean, etc.)?  Or am I just overthinking this, and Java will do the conversion for me?  :confused:

Comment: [Off-topic]: Classes should be named using UppercaseStartingCamelCase (so `argsDataHolder` should be `ArgsDataHolder`).

Comment: A static method on which class?  The various "boxed" objects (Integer, Long, Boolean) etc have `valueOf()` methods, but they're (a) static and (b) don't have a common ancestory.  You'd have to reflectively call the method, rather than `thisArgClass.valueOf(thisArgString)`.

Comment: You have two successive lines that assign a value to `thisArg` -- is that a "typo"?

Comment: Michael, If you know that variable type of the right side is an Integer, Long, Float, Double, String and whatever, thisArg = (String) thisArgClass will work. If you dont know then you have to use instanceOf -- http://www.java-samples.com/showtutorial.php?tutorialid=332

Comment: @vajapravin: can you write that up as an answer (with more detail), because I don't understand your comment.

Comment: @GregKopff Sorry I deleted that because it looks like I did indeed already try calling it as a static method, and yeah, it didn't work.  Umm... reflectively call it... so... `Method valueOfMethod = thisArgClass.getMethod("valueOf", String.class);  thisArgClass = valueOfMethod.invoke(null, thisArgString)`?

Comment: @vajapravin I think you are converting the wrong way.  I am not wanting to convert a dynamic type to a String, but rather I want to convert a String to a dynamic type.

Comment: Michael: that's along the lines I meant yes - (sorry I don't have time at the moment to write you a fragment that I know works, or I'd have posted you an answer by now!)

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2127318/java-how-can-i-do-dynamic-casting-of-a-variable-from-one-type-to-another

Comment: Are you sure you need to use reflection?  This seems extremely advanced for someone with only 10 days experience in Java.

Comment: @JimGarrison Your method compiled.  I can only assume that it works.  Will let you know when I get this up and running!  (You get a +1 for now. ^_^)

Comment: @JimGarrison RE: it being advanced: It is indeed pretty tough!  I'm basically adding functionality to an example program (which already utilizes reflection) in an OReilly book (Learning Java, Third Edition).  They take the training wheels off in a hurry.  (I'm on page 210 out of ~875... only 25% done, so I can only imagine I'll be in way over my head soon.)  I consider myself to be pretty smart, but I'm struggling with this book.  It's definitely not for beginners.

Answer (score 1):

> I can't seem to be able to cast thisArg to thisArgClass (like so: thisArg = (thisArgClass)thisArgClass.newInstance();,

This will not work like this as you need to initialize `thisArgClass` first.This will produce compile time error. Change the code something like this:

```
Class thisArgClass = null;
try {
    Object thisArg = thisArgClass.newInstance();
} catch (InstantiationException ex) {
    Logger.getLogger(Test3.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
} catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
    Logger.getLogger(Test3.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
}
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Sorry... the `...` in the code was supposed to represent the parts where variables are assigned values.  I'll add that in to make that more clear.

Comment: @Michael OK so that it will be more clear to others as well and chances of getting answers will be more.

Answer (score 1):

There are several things wrong here.  I'll assume that `thisArgClass` has been set correctly; for your example it would contain `Integer.class`.  In order to invoke `newInstance()` on a `Class` object, the class *must* have a no-arg constructor. Class `Integer` does not have such a constructor, so you have to invoke one of the existing constructors using a more roundabout method:

```
Constructor<Object> c = thisArgClass.getConstructor(String.class);
Object i = c.newInstance(thisArgString);
```

Since you don't know the actual type of the object until runtime you must use `<Object>` and cast the result to the desired type before using the value.

Comment: I tried something like this earlier, but it didn't work.  I think I passed getConstructor() the wrong parameter type.  Will try your solution here in a sec.