# java cast and call a string as method on an object

Tags: java

I am using AOP to find the value of an instance variable before its going to be set and after it is set. So I am intercepting all `setxxx` methods and trying to do a `getxxx` before and after.

```
//actual instance
Object target = joinPoint.getTarget();
//Type of the instance
Class objectClass = target.getClass();
```

I want to call a string "getFirstName()" that is actually a method name on the actual instance (target). How can I do so

right now I can do the following

```
if (target instanceof User) {
    instanceVarCurrentValue = ((User) target).getFirstName();
}
```

But i cannot check for instance of for all objects in my project and for each class I will have to check all properties

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/

Comment: if you are going to use reflection I'd suggest using Apache's reflection utilities. There are lots of useful methods in there and it's much less boilerplate donkey work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use Reflection. You must find the method on class and invoke it.
Please see the below code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws NoSuchMethodException, IllegalAccessException, InvocationTargetException {
    User user = new User();
    String name = runMethod(user, "getFirstName");
    System.out.println(name);
}

private static String runMethod(Object instance, String methodName) throws NoSuchMethodException, InvocationTargetException, IllegalAccessException {
    Method method = instance.getClass().getMethod(methodName);
    return (String)method.invoke(instance);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The possible ways to solve this in Java is to write code that covers all cases with lots of if and else and instanceof expressions.

You will need to implement something like ObjectConverter as in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2127318/java-how-can-i-do-dynamic-casting-of-a-variable-from-one-type-to-another/2127365#2127365),

Or you can always use Java Reflection API.

Comment: You're saying there is only one way of doing this and then you giving another option ?

Comment: No problem I  just find it weird and wanted to let you know. Sorry if it sounds aggressive or something that was not my intention.

Answer (score 0):

My go-to solution for things like this is a handy library called [jOOR](http://code.google.com/p/joor/) - for 'Java Object Oriented Reflection'.  It's a fluent wrapper around Java's reflection tools, which lets you write code like so:

```
String firstName = on(target).call("getFirstName").get();
```

With the above, ANY object 'target' with a method called `getFirstName` will work here, and the `get()` will (try to) cast the result as a string.  Pretty handy if you know you only have to deal with a specific set of types that are guaranteed to have the methods you're interested in, but don't want to write and maintain an enormous if-else block.