# generic cast based on param

Tags: java, generics, casting

I need a "generic" cast based on a method param (className).
Something like this:

```
void save(DomainObject o, String className) {
    doSomething((className) o);
}
```

So I want to cast "o" right into an Object of the class "className".

I know how to instantiate an Object via the classname String, but are there any easy possibilities to manage my casting problem?

Comment: I like to use interfaces in cases like this. So your object ```o``` should implement the interface

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Reflection to do this...

```
void save(DomainObject o, String className) {
    Class<?> clazz = Class.forName(className);
    doSomething(clazz.cast(o));
}
```

You'll need to handle the potential class cast exception, but I'm sure you can manage that :)

See this response for further details: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2127384/5969411

Comment: Wonderful. Glad I could help :)

Answer (score 1):

In your case it seems you already have the class name as a `String`, in which case the answer by ManoDestra would be suitable. As an alternative though, you could also use this approach:

```
void save(DomainObject o, Class<?> type){       
    doSomething( type.cast(o) );
}
```

And then you'd call it like this:

```
save( myObject, Integer.class );
```

Comment: This is also an elegant solution :)

Comment: well, this looks even more comfortable for my case, thanks!