# Java: Method that returns either String or int

Tags: java, string, methods, int

A part of a small program I am coding:

```
String maxs = "";
int maxi = 0;
```

At this part I defined two variables as `int` and `String`.

```
public Class(String max){
   try {
           this.maxi = Integer.parseInt(max);
       }catch (Exception e){
           this.maxs = max;
       }
}
```

I think this way I will get to define one of both variables, if the String does not parse to int it will be saved as normal String.

Now I need to check what I need to return:

```
private TypeOfReturn getMax(){
    if(this.maxi == 0){
        // return maxs (return String)
    } else if (this.maxs.equals("")) {
        // return maxi (return int)
    } else return null;
}
```

The quastion is, how do I fill the missing parts of the method `getMax()`?

Is it even possiable in Java?

Comment: TypeOfReturn can be `Object`.

Comment: this.maxi = Integer.parseInt(max); where the max come from ?

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2127318/java-how-can-i-do-dynamic-casting-of-a-variable-from-one-type-to-another

Comment: Is this for a school assignment? Or is there another purpose for this in your program? There are probably many other ways that are better if this isnt a specific assignment.

Comment: @mustafacil Object did good job.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Use Object instead of TypeOfReturn**
You can change the TypeoOfReturn to Object and then return the respective types.

Answer (score 1):

Another way to find out fast if a string is a number or not, which is the main part of your program, is to use the lambda expressions in java 8 like this:

```
String max = "123";
boolean isNumber = max.chars().allMatch(Character::isDigit);
System.out.println(isNumber);
```

Which will give you the output

```
true
```

Answer (score 0):

Make your TypeOfReturn as String object type and convert the maxi as String  and return that String in your else if condition.

Note:  you cannot return both the  int and String in the Same method.

Comment: I changed the TypeOfReturn to Object. it did work. thanks anyway