# How to cast with the datatype stored in variable's value?

Tags: java

I want to do something like this:

```
String[] name=new String[5];
String[] type=new String[5];
name[0]="variable";
type[0]="int";
name[0]=(type[0])(<any value to be assigned>);
```

The main issue I'm facing is typecasting like this.It says ';' expected after type[0].

Comment: you cannot convert any value to Integer like this and moreover, you are trying to store the Integer value in a string array

Comment: @ShashankGupta please do no focus on the value part ,main part is to typecast when the datatype is stored in a variable

Comment: Please go through this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2127318/java-how-can-i-do-dynamic-casting-of-a-variable-from-one-type-to-another